# Where to change i18n default messages of client side in Grails?

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, internationalization

I have the next constraint in my domain object *usuario/Usuario.groovy*:

```
phone blank: false, matches: "[0-9 -+()]{3,15}"
```

And I have in *i18n/messages_es.properties*:

```
usuario.telefono.matches=Se admiten números, espacios y los caracteres: -+(). Se admiten entre 3 y 15 caracteres en total.
```

This is the error message if the phone doesn't match the pattern:

[image: client side error message]

The translation of the message would be something like: "Please, adjust the requested format"

I have not any similar error message in any of the i18n/messages... files. It looks a client side error message as it appears instantly.

In create gsp there is the next code (I think the error message could come from here):

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${usuarioInstance}">
<bootstrap:alert class="alert-error">
<ul>
    <g:eachError bean="${usuarioInstance}" var="error">
    <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
    </g:eachError>
</ul>
</bootstrap:alert>
</g:hasErrors>
```

How could I change this error message by a custom one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand: this message is html form validation error and doesn't connected to your application messages. So the fix will be in html. Try to add **oninvalid** attribut to input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" pattern="[0-9 -+()]{3,15}" required="" value="" id="phone" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please, type valid phone number')">
```

You can move *'Please, type valid phone number'* to i18n file

**Edit**: if you use fields plugin add **oninvalid** attr with **input-** prefix.

```
<f:field bean="${usuarioInstance}" property="phone" input-oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please, type valid phone number')"/>
```

Comment: That is what I thought, but the related code of the phone in my gsp file (using [Grails fields plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/fields)) is: `<f:field bean="${usuarioInstance}" property="phone" />` So where that error message come from? :/

Comment: From browser, man. "The first thing you have to understand: this message is html form validation error and doesn't connected to your application messages"

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. Just curious, do you know where the original messages come from?

Comment: It works. I think joining your answer with the @TP_JAVA's one will give me an i18n client-side translation.

Comment: Yes, as I said before, move to text i18n file and have fun

Comment: The following works: `<f:field bean="${usuarioInstance}" property="phone" input-oninvalid="setCustomValidity('${message(code:"your.localized.message.code")}')" />` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing 'invalid' as part of the message key.

Use the following error code for matches:

```
className.propertyName.matches.invalid = 'errorMessage'..
```

Comment: Nope. Still the same error message after adding `.invalid`. Another "curiosity" it that if I change the language to English (typing _http://localhost:8080/webAlojamientoUCA/usuario/create?lang=en_), that error message keep being in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Still if it doesn't work ..try the following approach.

Add def messageSource in controller /service.

user.errors?.allErrors?.each{ 
println  messageSource.getMessage(it, null)
};

Go through the following link which explains this better

http://johnrellis.blogspot.com/2010/02/retrieve-grails-domain-errors-from.html

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll see it later with more time.

Comment: I think that doesn't get the client-side error messages. Server-side error messages are displaying well in my Internet Browser. Feel free to check the answer of @Mr.Cat :)